# Table with rows and columns, iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is it possible to create a table in iphone sdk with custom number of rows and columns? I know to create a table using uitableview, unfortunately, it has a fixed number of columns and is 1. I want to get a view something like the image gallery of the iphone. is that possible? pls give your suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the TTThumbsViewController in [Three20](http://wiki.github.com/facebook/three20).

Comment: I think its TTThumbsViewController.